# Merging two emails together in Outlook 2016

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook

I have set up Outlook so that it already groups emails of the same subject together so that I can follow the conversation history, much like gmail's standard set up.

However, my boss has sent me and only me an email that is related to a previous chain but the subject line slightly differs (like "V8 Juice Prices_2019.xlsx" vs "V8 Juice Prices"). So now there are two streams of messages going that I have to keep track of. Is there a way to tie the two together?

Comment: I do this a lot and I just keep Emails of a given subject in one folder and then organized by date but I can sort as needed.

Comment: I tend to organize by sender (so each person has their own folder). I'd like to avoid amending my folder scheme.

Comment: You can open a message and edit it. First copy the text of email from one message into Notepad (for clarity of work) and then open the other message and paste the added content into it. You can open an email into its own window and edit it.

Comment: I am afraid there is no built-in method to merge two emails together.

Comment: You cannot merge emails but you can copy the necessary contents of one to the other email

Comment: You can edit the subject (ask me how if needed) and change it to that of another conversation but this won't automatically merge the e-mail message into that conversation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sorry for the delay!. Yes, there's no built-in method released by Outlook desktop, but there're a lot of plug-ins doing this (it will be really useful!), for example here you have a free web app doing this:

https://products.aspose.app/email/merger

From: https://products.aspose.app/email/family

EDIT:
What to explain?. the link points to a web utility which do that thing. It's a free utility provided by a company. I also have found that the way to repair outlook redundance, is to do the reverse operation, instead of merging, you need to split and only keep the first EMail, if the other ones match another individual EMail already in the mail box. Cause people has been sending EMails with the option of include original EMail in reply. I found this option is useless, if you need to forward an EMail to another person not included in the people list, you can merge conversations, printing them (Outlook does this automatically if you choose it), and send this PDF to that new integrant. Attached files are a problem with this method cause you need to include all one by one I think...

Good luck!.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1139323)

Comment: Thanks for the info, sorry for my newbiance :X

Comment: @RohitGupta Sorry, have you worked with cooper tires?? hahahaa

Comment: Just explain whats in the link, a short summary. I  dont get the joke about cooper tires.

Comment: Sorry, I thought you were a colleague of mine in cooper tires client & Prokarma consulting...

Comment: Now that you have expanded your answer, I have upvoted it.

Comment: Wow, talk about a blast from the past! I don't even work there and haven't since Feb 2020 lol! Thanks for the answer and should I ever use Outlook again, I'll refer to this answer. Welcome to Stack Exchange (sorry for the delay myself)